# Automatic receipts on imported renewal contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

I have been reading all the earlier Q/A on this matter but I found no real solution, so bear with me:

I am trying to send automatic receipts of renewal payments to CiviCRM. I have discovered a means (by external data-bases) to automatically renew/update memberships (to end of next year) and also register the contribution automatically, via import Membership, Import Contribution. Now I also wish to send the automatic receipt, but I have found no way to achieve that, as the Activity "Membership Renewal" is set by the manual transaction, but not set by my automatic imported contribution update (I believe, actually impossible to test on a live database, if things go wrong). So I created the new Activity "Automatic Renewal" hoping it could be easily linked to my import (the "Automatic Renewal" under the extensive roll-down list on selection of import fields). But it did not appear. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Perhaps there is another more obvious way to achieve what I wish to do, and I would be grateful to hear your views on this matter.

Comment: When you say 'automatic' do you mean 'send the receipt immediately following the Contribution (or Membership) import'?

Comment: No, I mean that the Cron Job(or whatever does it) should react to the fact that a payment (or renewal) has been done. Could be done once away or week or so. I seek the magic link that causes the system to recognise that a renewal has occurred, the system can react to that and sent the receipt. Hope this clarifies somewhat!